Where do I find the requirement for an AFM to be serial number specific?
It seems to be generally accepted that an AFM must be serial number specific to that aircraft it was made for and delivered with. I am having difficulty finding the reference for "serial number specific".

Is it just English? The AFM of an specific aircraft should be linked to the aircraft (as serial number, not just model, type, variant, year, line, etc.).

Yes, Understood the AFM should be linked. Is there regulatory directive stating as much?

Ok, so I think I misinterpreted your * I have found all the references that states such*, which make more sense

My apologies for the confusion. I will rephrase.

I'm puzzled.  If you have found "all the references" saying an AFM must be specific to an individual airframe, how could there be any doubt that it needs to be serial number specific since that is the means by which they are differentiated?

Thank you for the response Micheal I rephrased the question removing the "all" comment.

For the US, the FAA says in 25.1581-1 (Airplane Flight Manual):

The AFM may address either a single airplane model (i.e., hardware build) or several models of the same airplane type.


If information is provided for more than one model, the AFM should clearly identify which operating limitations, operating procedures, and performance information apply to each model (e.g., by model designation, serial number, etc.).


If the AFM format is such that different pages apply to different airplanes, the log of pages should clearly
identify the specific pages of the AFM that apply to each airplane.

Thus if the AFM provides specific information applying to a specific serial number, it must specify this number. Else it has to specify the appropriate level for which it is written, it can be the model or even the type. The serial number may appear only on pages which are serial number dependent, and not on the other pages.
It is frequent to see serial numbers or registration IDs specified on some pages of the manufacturer or operator FCOM.
